# Software that allows me to trigger Python scripts with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: osx, python, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to quickly run Python scripts I frequently use whenever I want. Is there software like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for osx that allows me to trigger Python scripts with arbitrary keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What is "Keyboard Maestro"? What of its features you need, and why can't you just use "Keyboard Maestro" itself? Any price limit?

Comment: You do realize that there is nothing Python specific here, don't you? You just need a hotkey program which will execute any command, including the Python interpreter, with your script as a a parameter, when a given key combination is entered.

Comment: And what is wrong with Keyboard Maestro, to which you refer?

Comment: [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) does this well